# Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a trivial example of Executors and Threads.

When I call `newSingleThreadExecutor(new CustomThreadFactory)` it goes well, but when I call `newSingleThreadExecutor(null)` with null parameter it gives me "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Why?

```
private Executor creador = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(null); //at this point fails, and with no parameters everything goes well
private QRExplorer explorer; // this class implements Runnable
//...
public MainView()
{
   //...
   explorer = new QRExplorer();
}
private void pCamaraMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
{                                     
      creador.execute(explorer); 
}
```

Comment: Where is the code terminating, on the line that you call newSingleThreadExecutor() or another one?

Comment: I just added code.  thanks for responding

Comment: Sorry for that, I just get confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(null);
```

you're trying to invoke the `newSingleThreadExecutor` overload that accepts a `ThreadFactory` argument. You're passing the value `null` as that single argument.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-) of that method states

> Throws:
>
> - `NullPointerException` - if `threadFactory` is `null`

Since you're passing `null`, the invocation will throw `NullPointerException`.